# react-hook useFormInput() form validation not working

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks

Link to code sandbox https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdv6mx?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/ResetPassword.js

**EXPLANATION:** **When the user enters incorrect details, the server sends 400: bad request error with a message which can be seen in the `Response tab` under the network's tab. The intention is to validate the form fields before submitting the form and display an error message(s) if incorrect fields are entered. Also, the intention is to disable to reset the button until the form fields match the criteria. So, that will prevent the user from accidentally submitting half-entered fields.**

I have a functional component in which I have a simple form.

PROBLEM: I am calling `validatForm()` method on `onChange`. The method should first check that the newPassword and confirmPassword are the same and are as per the password rules(requirements) and if true, only then, send the data.

UPDATED CODE IS IN THE STACKBLITZ LINK ABOVE.

I am use `useFormInput()` like below

```
  const email = useFormInput("");
  const newPassword = useFormInput("");
  const confirmPassword = useFormInput("");
```

and I have written a `useFormInput()` method

```
const useFormInput = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  };
};
```

and a `validateForm()` method and I am passing it my `<button/>`

```
/*  Your password must contain at least one capital letter, one
      *number and one lowercase letter, and it must contain at least 8
      *characters*/


const validateForm = (event) => {
    let pass = event.target.value;
    let reg = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/;
    let test = reg.test(pass);
    if (test) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    } else {
      alert("password validation unsuccessful. Please try again.");
      return;
    }
  };
```

and in render()

```
<FormGroup row>
            <Label for="Email" sm={2}>
              Email
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="Email"
                
                {...email}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="newPassword" sm={2}>
              New Password
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="newPassword"
                
                {...newPassword}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="confirmPassword" sm={2}>
              Confirm Password
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="password"
                name="confirmPassword"
                id="confirmPassword"
                
                {...confirmPassword}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <div className="form-actions">
            {error && (
              <>
                <small style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</small>
                <br />
              </>
            )}
            <br />

            <Col lg={{ offset: 2 }} sm={{ size: 1 }}>
              <Button
                className="mail-reset-btn"
                block
                type="submit"
                value={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
                onClick={handleReset}
                disabled={!validateForm}
              >
                Reset
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </div>
        </Form>
```

Comment: `this.setState` ?

Comment: You've `disabled={!validateForm}` on the submit button, `validateForm` isn't invoked. I also don't understand why you've mixed together a submit and reset button.

Comment: for `disabled`: the idea is to disable the reset button if the form fields are invalid. 
for `onclick` on reset: that's a mistake. I forget to remove it. I intend to go with `onSubmit`

Comment: @SakoBu  I'm sorry, I do not follow. kindly elaborate

Comment: `ResetPassword` is a functional component, so calling `this.setState` is completely invalid. When are you trying to validate the form fields? On submit?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, I want to validate them on OnSubmit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `validateForm` to destructure the password fields from the form `onSubmit` event. Create an `errors` object to track what field errors there are. If the `errors` object is empty then validation passes, otherwise set error state.

```
const validateForm = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { confirmPassword, newPassword } = event.target;
  const errors = {};

  const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/;

  if (!regex.test(newPassword.value)) {
    errors.requirementUnmet = "New password does not meet requirements.";
  }

  if (newPassword.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
    errors.passwordMismatch = "Entered passwords do not match.";
  }

  if (!Object.keys(errors).length) {
    alert("password validation successful.");
    setError(null);
    return;
  }

  setError(errors);
};
```

Attach `validateForm` to the form's `onSubmit` handle.

```
<Form onSubmit={validateForm}>
```

Ensure you've a type="submit" button in the form.

```
<Button
  className="mail-submit-btn"
  block
  type="submit"
  value={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cez4x3?file=src/ResetPassword.js) (*though I've not an account so copying updated code below.*)

***Note:** I simply `JSON.stringify(error)` the error for simplicity, but you'll want to render this more gracefully.*

## Entire ResetPassword.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Col,
  Label,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter
} from "reactstrap";

const useFormInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange
  };
};

const ResetPassword = props => {
  // form inputs
  const email = useFormInput("");
  const newPassword = useFormInput("");
  const confirmPassword = useFormInput("");
  // using hooks
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  const validateForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { confirmPassword, newPassword } = event.target;
    const errors = {};

    const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/;

    if (!regex.test(newPassword.value)) {
      errors.requirementUnmet = "New password does not meet requirements.";
    }

    if (newPassword.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      errors.passwordMismatch = "Entered passwords do not match.";
    }

    if (!Object.keys(errors).length) {
      alert("password validation successful.");
      setError(null);
      return;
    }

    setError(errors);
  };

  const handleReset = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError(null);
    setLoading(true);
    // some unrelated redux code
  };

  return (
    <div className="mail-reset" id="forgotPassword">
      <div className="mail-reset-content">
        <Form onSubmit={validateForm}>
          <h3 className="form-title">Enter Information</h3>

          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="Email" sm={2}>
              Email
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="Email"
                placeholder="Email"
                aria-label="email address"
                aria-describedby="email address"
                aria-invalid="false"
                {...email}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="newPassword" sm={2}>
              New Password
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="newPassword"
                placeholder="New Password"
                aria-label="new password"
                aria-describedby="new password"
                aria-invalid="false"
                {...newPassword}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="confirmPassword" sm={2}>
              Confirm Password
            </Label>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Input
                type="password"
                name="confirmPassword"
                id="confirmPassword"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                aria-label="new password"
                aria-describedby="new password"
                aria-invalid="false"
                {...confirmPassword}
              />
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>

          <div className="modal-wrapper">
            <Col sm={{ size: 4, offset: 2 }}>
              <Button onClick={toggle} className="passwordReqBtn">
                Password Requirements
              </Button>
            </Col>
            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} className="mail-reset-modal">
              <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Password Requirements</ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
                Your password must contain at least one capital letter, one
                number and one lowercase letter, and it must contain at least 8
                characters
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button onClick={toggle} className="btn-modal pull-right">
                  OK
                </Button>{" "}
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
          </div>

          <div className="form-actions">
            {error && (
              <>
                <small style={{ color: "red" }}>{JSON.stringify(error)}</small>
                <br />
              </>
            )}
            <br />

            <Col lg={{ offset: 2 }} sm={{ size: 1 }}>
              <Button
                className="mail-reset-btn"
                block
                type="submit"
                value={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
              <Button
                className="mail-reset-btn"
                block
                type="reset"
                value={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
                onClick={handleReset}
              >
                Reset
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResetPassword;
```

Comment: for some reason, `form-actions` is not rendering. I've attached an image of DOM https://imgur.com/a/DQoW7Z7

Comment: @NaumanTanwir Odd, there should at least be a `Col` and a `Button` in there, right? Is this in your stackblitz, or dev machine on localhost (or other)?

Comment: yes, its my local. sorry, just noticed something. In stackblitz, the error message appears on click of `Submit button`. how do I get it to appear on `RESET` button?
PS: there are two button: submit and reset.

Comment: @NaumanTanwir I didn't change anything there in my solution, but in your stackblitz `handleReset` is the onClick handler for the reset button and it clears the error(s) by calling `setError(null);`. What error would/could be displayed when the form is reset?

Comment: my bad, I should had explained it better. RESET button will first validate the form fields and if they are valid then it will send the details to the server. That is what RESET button is being used for. one button to it all. So RESET Button has to use both `validateform()` and `handleReset()`

Comment: @NaumanTanwir Basically my opinion, but that is a terrible idea. Submit and reset are intrinsically ***very different*** actions. Are you simply wanting the form to reset when submitted? If a user partially enters data and clicks that button, do you reset the form or submit it? See how confusing that is? From an accessibility standpoint alone that is a logistical nightmare.

Comment: great point. As of now, the intention is to disable to `reset` button until the form fields match the criteria. So, that will prevent the user from accidentally submitting half-entered fields. And redirect the user back to login page upon a successful password reset. To redirect, I have got a dipatch() in `handleReset()` to care of it. I'll add that to the stackblitz for some clarity.

Comment: updated stackblitz with that snippet but commented it to avoid unnecessary errors

Comment: @NaumanTanwir Previously you said you wanted validation to occur when the form was submitted, but it sounds more like you want form validation on blur (or change) of the fields. It's late and I must get going, but I can take a look at your updated stackblitz later.

Comment: yea apologies for the confusion. That'd be great. thanks.